# Pandas - Can't get Series.isin to work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe of race results and I am trying to see if the winner of the race is from the same location as the race.

round_loc column:

```
0                       Val d'Allos, France
168                  Les Deux Alpes, France
378                    Winter Park, CO, USA
499                    Whistler, BC, Canada
...
```

country column:

```
0              France
168            France
378            France
499         Australia
602            France
...
```

My Code:

```
winners_df = df.loc[df['finish_position'] == 1, ['country', 'round_loc']]
hometown_win = winners_df['country'].isin(winners_df['round_loc'])

# Also tried

hometown_win = winners_df['country'].isin(winners_df['round_loc'].values)

print(hometown_win)
```

My results:

```
0       False
168     False
378     False
499     False
602     False
...
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
winners_df['country'][0] in winners_df['round_loc'][0]
```

Works fine. I'm sure I could just do it with a loop but I feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: This won't work `isin` is looking for exact matches, you want to compare each row and use `contains` to test for membership/matches here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print (winners_df)
                  round_loc    country
0       Val d'Allos, France     France
168  Les Deux Alpes, France        USA <-changed data sample
378    Winter Park, CO, USA     France
499    Whistler, BC, Canada  Australia
```

If need check if in column `round_loc` is one value from column `country`:

```
a = '|'.join(winners_df['country'].unique().tolist())
print (a)
France|USA|Australia

hometown_win = winners_df['round_loc'].str.contains(a)
print(hometown_win)
0       True
168     True
378     True
499    False
Name: round_loc, dtype: bool
```

If need check if in column `round_loc` is one value from column `country`, but per row:

```
hometown_win = winners_df.apply(lambda x: x['country'] in x['round_loc'],axis=1)
print(hometown_win)
0       True
168    False
378    False
499    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense. Theres seems like there might be a problem here if there is a race in France (round_loc) that isn't won by someone in France (country) as each row contains a racer.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you! I didn't know you could check all the items on an axis like that!